# Firebase problems java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i suffer this problem while calling a function that have this ligne:FirebaseAuth.getInstances();

this is problem when i call this function :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.probadr98.trollapp-1/base.apk)
W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
              at com.probadr98.trollapp.DB.addToDB(LoginFragment.java:223)
              at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
              at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:9)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

this funtion that do this problem:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();





    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering......");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(jemail, jpassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener <AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Register!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.probadr98.trollapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

can someone help me to delete this problem and sorry about any mistakes in english because not my original language!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up incompatible versions of Firebase libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

Your dependencies for storage, database, and auth are way out of date compared to core.  You should set them all to their most recent versions listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Comment: sir when i do what you give i suffer this problem:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6.
Open File
Show Details

Comment: You should probably go back to that page of documentation I linked and make sure you followed all of the setup instructions.

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case, I was using `force: true` at `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'` and after removing that, the problem disappeared. Would you know why `force: true` might cause the crashes?